# How to make Transperency for background image without changing the transperency of the text in it in html?

Tags: html, css

How can i make the background image of a div transperent without changing the transperency of the text in it.?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the image itself and then save it in the PNG format (the only web format that supports translucency).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can't do it. You could use absolute positioning and z-indexes to create the same effect. Just changing the background image transparency in an editor and saving it to png would be the best way to do this.